# Is it possible to install bundle assets directly in web/ directory?

Tags: php, assets, symfony

By default, symfony takes a bundle's assets from the bundle's `public/` directory and installs them in `web/bundles/bundlename/`.

Is it possible to install those assets directly in `web/` instead?

Comment: Why?  Most things are possible but given that the assets are automatically copied then I don't see the point.

Comment: Took me a few tries but I see what you are asking.  There is no option for what you want to do.  If two bundles happen to have assets with the same name then one would overwrite the other.  On the hand, it would be easy enough to clone the existing asset install command and tweak it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/bundles/` part is pretty much [hardcoded](https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/43e1aa715cd366209972af22bf56781e0b0b1693/Command/AssetsInstallCommand.php#L91) so there's no built in support for such assets installation. I believe you'll be best served by implementing your own command for this task.

Answer (score 1):

Simply never call `assets:install`, and list the assets you want in your template :

```
{% javascripts '@VendorBundle/Resources/public/js/*' %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.